# Using Python 3.3 to access blocked webpages

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to download webpages off the internet. I'm able to steal the HTML (with URLlib), but I can't download images correctly. There's already a question for that though. My question is, **is there any way I can use python to bypass a firewall to access 'blocked' webpages?**

Ideally it would be using some obscure code or module, but if it's impossible, could someone tell me a good workaround using a different method (like a proxy)?

Comment: Bypassing a firewall (at least a 'real' firewall) has nothing to do with Python or any other programming language; it's purely at the network level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract images from a HTML page, you need to parse it with **re** module

```
import re
```

using regex to extract only the *img src* tag. You can also use a parser alredy written. For example BeautifulSoup > http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

A firewall is a passive component of a perimeter defense into a computer network that can also serve as contact points between two or more sections of the network, ensuring a protection in terms of security of the network itself. So you have to work directly in the network, not through the code language.

Comment: I know you can't change the network setting easily, but is there a way of hiding what you are getting off the internet from it with python?

Comment: I don't think it is possible directly with Python, unless you do not work with encryption protocols such as SSL / TLS or HTTPS in an  already "protected" environment.